# Chassis Intrusion API?

Tags: security, intrusion-detection

Some computer cases come with [chassis intrusion detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_case#Intrusion_detection).

I'd like my application to check for chassis intrusion on start-up and if an intrusion is detected to display an error and shut down.

Is there a standard way of reading this value programmatically? Is a BIOS password coupled with chassis intrusion detection reasonably difficult to work around in laptops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally chassis intrusion info is available (on recent motherboards, recent being <5 years old) in the System Management BIOS (SMBIOS) or Desktop Management Interface (DMI) tables. Look at [this](http://setaoffice.com/2009/03/16/get_hardware_information_under_linux/) for info about the DMI entries: there is one that gives up some form of chassis intrusion info. The console tool `dmidecode` lets you get at that info on Linux: I'm sure there's a Windows programming interface, just don't quite know what it is. You can probably break open the source for `dmidecode` and that should give you a good start.

Good luck.